# How counterReducer is generated in Redux tutorial sample

Tags: redux

I am reading the Redux official tutorial. I surprised when I see the `counterReducer` which there is not in any modules bu has value and works! I couldn't find any description of it but :

> Since we know that the counterReducer function is coming from
> features/counter/counterSlice.js, let's see what's in that file, piece
> by piece.

I even change the name of the **slicer** to the counter3 but it still works!

Can anyone describe to me please how it is generated?

**counterSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter3',
  initialState: {
    value: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    increment: state => {
      state.value += 1;
    },
    decrement: state => {
      state.value -= 1;
    },
    incrementByAmount: (state, action) => {
      state.value += action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions;

export const incrementAsync = amount => dispatch => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    dispatch(incrementByAmount(amount));
  }, 1000);
};

export const selectCount = state => state.counter.value;

export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

**store.js**  (We use it in store.js module)

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import counterReducer from '../features/counter/counterSlice';  //HERE IS THE IMPORTING PLACE

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    counter: counterReducer,
  },
});
```

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure#creating-slice-reducers-and-actions

Comment: Afraid it's not clear what you're asking. What aspect of the the slice creation / naming /importing thing are you specifically finding confusing?  What do you mean by "how it's generated" ?

Comment: @markerikson There is no counterReducer  in the counterSlice.js but in the store.js it is imported. My question is what is the counterReducer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `counterSlice.js` is using an ES6 "default export" to export the reducer function generated by `createSlice`:

```js
export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

Any other file can then use a "default import" to get a reference to that reducer function.  However, when we default import a value, we can give it any name we want:

```js
// fileA.js
import counterReducer from "./features/counter/counterSlice"

// fileB.js
import someReducer from "./features/counter/counterSlice"

// fileC.js
import fred from "./features/counter/counterSlice"
```

All three of those variables will point to the same reducer function - it's just a question of what the local variable name is that we've created.

So, in this case, the `counterReducer` variable in `store.js` is a reference to the reducer function that was exported from the `counterSlice.js` file.